# What is the correct way to set build specific variables in Bamboo?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I am currently running a simple ios build script task with Bamboo that uses the following variables:

```
XCODE_APP=/Applications/Xcode.app

WORKSPACE="/Users/user/Desktop/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/ISC-IOS-JOB1/src/xcode"
RELEASE_ID=27959
RELEASE_NAME="releasename"
DEVICE="Universal"
TARGET="Release-Name"
BUNDLE_ID="com.xxx.releasename"
BUILD_CONFIG="Release"
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME="Profile.mobileprovision"
```

My question is this:

Should I create Global variables and then use a variable inject task to set them in Bamboo from a properties file OR is there a better way to set and use variables on a build to build basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are the same for each plan, then you can set up a build task such that the 'options' pass the command line variables for setting those fields to the task.

Otherwise, you might wish to create a script which calls the task directly after setting those environment variables (with the environment variables hard coded).  An advanced version would allow passing of those variables as options to the script.